# Protecting against base64 injection attacks in cfmail

Tags: coldfusion, base64, cfml, coldfusion-2016, cfmail

I have a REST web service that accepts a bunch of fields. These fields are going have processing and eventually become part of an email.

[image]

When I am building up the email, the field called `message.image` will later become `rc.image` and it will be added to the HTML email via

```
...
var body &= "<p><img src='#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(rc.image)#' alt='#EncodeForHTMLAttribute(rc.image_name)#'></p>"; 
...
```

My concern is that this could be still be vulnerability

Comment: I'm sure you're sanitizing the content of the text fields, but are you verifying the content of the image upload is actually an image with the correct mime-type and not some kind of data packet?

Comment: I am not doing any verifying right now. I am not sure what kind of verifying even needs to be done.

Comment: It's basically an upload, so most anything that applies to image file uploads is probably applicable https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unrestricted_File_Upload

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno To quote the great Pete Freitag, "Never trust a mime."  :-)  https://www.petefreitag.com/presentations/cfsummit/2015/security-workshop.pdf

Comment: @Shawn Yes, that's why I use a library like https://github.com/arimus/jmimemagic to validate the file's mime-type on the server as part of the upload validation routine.